# PostgreSQL - CREATE EXTENSION only per connection

Tags: postgresql

I am using `unaccent` extension in my PostgreSQL database.

I install it by

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS unaccent
```

and then within a connection it runs fine. But when I reconnect to the database i run `unaccent` function and it throws error `function unaccent(character varying) does not exist` and I need to run `CREATE EXTENSION ...` again. Then it works fine.

My problem is that I need to run the `unaccent` extension everytime I connect to the database without the need to re-create it.

What should I do to enable `unaccent` for every connection.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you aren't committing after creating the extension?  You should only have to install it once.

Comment: @Jeremy thanks a lot, that did the trick :) ... I am new to PostgreSQL. Feel free to put it as answer. I will mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CREATE EXTENSION command should only need to be run once.  If you ran it in a transaction, the transaction will need to be committed to ensure that future connections can use it.